# Handlebars won't render HTML

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, react-fullstack

I'm new to using handlebars and struggling to figure out why the html I want won't render at all. Handlebars seems to only throw me blank pages.

I suspect it has something to do with the {{{body}}} tag not being picked up on as a term by the handlebars package.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
const express = require('express')
const engine = require('express')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')

//Load config
dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env'})

const app = express()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

//Handlebars
app.engine('.hbs', engine({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}))
app.set('view engine', '.hbs')
app.set('views', './views');

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'))


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen(
  PORT, 
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} made on port ${PORT}`)
)
```

Index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

// @Desc Login/Landing page
// @route GET /
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', {layout: 'main'})
})

//@Desc Dashboard
// @route GET /dashboard
router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  res.render('dashboard', {layout: 'main'})
})

module.exports = router
```

main.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    <title>FW Pre-Call-Script Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     {{{body}}}
  </body>
</html>
```

and dashboard.hbs

```
---
layout: 'main'
---
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
```

super simple. I just want it to render "Dashboard" in h1 font at localhost:3000/dashboard, but it doesn't return anything at all at the address. It's not that the address is invalid - just no HTML is getting through.

I tried all the basic troubleshooting. Here's a list of my folders and files.
[photo of folders and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AMxh.png)

Any idea what's up?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `exphbs` import. You are actually importing `express` twice, and the second time you are assigning it to the variable `engine`. But the `engine` you want is the one that is exported by `express-handlebars`. Therefore, you should remove the second `express` import and destructure the `epxress-handlebars` import so as to get the reference to the correct `engine`:

```
const express = require('express')
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars')
```

Comment: @SatvikAgnihotri You're welcome. If the instructions in my post helped you to resolve your issue, you might want to consider marking it as the accepted answer.